# How to get numpy arrays indexing equivalent in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a numpy **array** as following:

```
    array([[1, 2],
           [3, 4],
           [5, 6],
           [7, 8]])
```

The array is called myArray, and I perform two indexing operations on the 2D array and get following results:

```
    In[1]: a1 = myArray[1:]
           a1

    Out[1]:array([[3, 4],
                 [5, 6],
                 [7, 8]])


    In[2]: a2 = myArray[:-1]
           a2

    Out[2]:array([[1, 2],
                  [3, 4],
                  [5, 6]])
```

Now, I have the same data in the form of a pandas df in two columns, let the data frame be df

```
      x    y
   0  1    2
   1  3    4
   3  5    6
   4  7    8
```

How to do the equivalent indexing/ slicing on two columns to get the same results as above for a1 and a2.

Comment: You can access the underlying numpy object using `df.values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[1:]

#   x   y
#1  3   4
#3  5   6
#4  7   8

df.iloc[:-1]

#   x   y
#0  1   2
#1  3   4
#3  5   6
```

Use `head/tail`:

```
df.head(-1)       # equivalent to df.iloc[:-1]

#   x   y
#0  1   2
#1  3   4
#3  5   6

df.tail(-1)       # equivalent to df.iloc[1:]

#   x   y
#1  3   4
#3  5   6
#4  7   8
```

Comment: What if there are more columns in the df, and I just want to get the results on"x" and "y" columns. I know I can delete the columns after indexing, but is there a way to perform indexing on selected columns only?

Comment: How about `df[['x', 'y']].iloc[1:]`? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I wanted.

Comment: @Psidom how to select multiple line which doesnt follow each other? e.g select lines from list=[1,10,25,100]